# Is it OK to use 'private' NSNotification names?

Tags: ios, private, appstore-approval, nsnotificationcenter

I am implementing a drop-in component for iOS that lets you present a slide-in notification view. To make it short: I need to respond to events where NSNavigationController is pushing or popping windows.

I am currently listening to `UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification`, which is not in the documentation but can easily be found when listening for all notification names (using the `nil` paramter for `name`).

**The question is: Will that pass App Review or will the app get rejected?**

I am aware and OK with with the fact that Apple might change the notification name, etc., but as a drop-in cannot always be the `UINavigationController`'s delegate, I don't see another solution right now.

Thanks for your help,

Christian

**UPDATE**

[Official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID) does not explicitly forbid registering for all notifications being sent to yout app. Technically, it doesn't make much difference whether you register for all notifications and check for the notification name or whether you just register for that specific notification. After all, it might even result in a very little performance improvement

Comment: Alternatively you could use the UINavigationControllerDelegate method navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that it is **not ok** to listen for this notification and it may lead to **rejection** of your app. Apple clearly says that you should not use `API`s which are not exposed.

You should use `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method of [`UINavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3awillShowViewController%3aanimated%3a) protocol to know when the `UINavigationController` shows a view controller. You can post your own notification there to let your other objects know about the event.

Comment: I know about their restrictions on private APIs. But NSNotificationCenter names are not really an API... As I explained above: I can't become delegate...

Comment: for all intents and purposes they are included in what Apple means when they say "API"

Comment: It's hard to say what Apple treats as a part of the private API. My opinion is that if they are not in the documentation, then you should not use it. You can also easily extract names of private methods and call them. For me it's the same thing as registering for all kinds of notifications and extracting names of the undocumented ones.

Comment: too bad, would be such a sweet solution ;(

Comment: All I found was this article: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/110199-is-this-an-undocumented-call.html

Comment: Well, you can try and see if they reject your app. I am curious.

Comment: Official Apple Documenation does not explicitly forbid registering for all notifications being sent to yout app. Technically, it doesn't make much difference whether you register for all notifications and check for the notification name or whether you just register for that specific notification. After all, it might even result in a very little performance improvement... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID